# $f$ is factored into many same degree irreducible polynomials.

Tags: field-theory

I met a problem when I study about Galois field and do this exercise. Hopefully, someone can help me.

Suppose that $L/K$ is normal extension and $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X]$. Prove that if $f$ is reducible in $L$ then $f$ is factored into many same degree irreducible polynomials.

The first solution:

Because $f$ is an irreducible polynomial then $f$ can be written by $f_{1}f_{2}...f_{m}$ with $f_{i}$ is irreducible.
$\alpha_{i}$ and $\alpha_{j}$ are roots of $f_{i}$ and $f_{j}$. We need to show that $degf_{i}=degf_{j}$
It suffices to show that $[L(\alpha_{i}) : L]=[L(\alpha_{j}) : L]$

- $[L(\alpha_{i}) : L][L : K]=[L(\alpha_{i}) : K]=[L(\alpha_{i}) : K]= [L(\alpha_{i} : K(\alpha_{i})][K(\alpha_{i}) :K]$.
- $[L(\alpha_{j}) : L][L : K]=[L(\alpha_{j}) : K]=[L(\alpha_{j}) : K]= [L(\alpha_{j} : K(\alpha_{j})][K(\alpha_{j}) :K]$.

But $f$ is irreducible in $K[X]$ then $degf=[K(\alpha_{j}) :K]=[K(\alpha_{i}) :K]$.
Moreover, $\phi$ is homomorphism from $K(\alpha_{i})$ to $K(\alpha_{j})$, $\phi(a)=a$, $a\in K$, $\phi(\alpha_{i})=\alpha_{j}$. It is isomorphism then creates an isomorphism from $L(\alpha_{i})$ to $L(\alpha_{j})$.
WED.
I do not understand why "It is isomorphism then creates an isomorphism from $L(\alpha_{i})$ to $L(\alpha_{j}).$"

However, I saw another solution that is:
Call that $H$ is the seperate field of $L$ and $G=Gal(H/L)$. Take $\phi$ in $G$ we have $\phi(\alpha_{i})=\alpha_{j}$ then $\phi(f_{i})$ is irreducible and $\alpha_{j}$ is a root of it. Because $f_{i}$, $f_{j}$ and $\phi_(f_{i})$ are irreducible so degree of them is equal.

I do not know why $\phi(f_{i})$ is irreducible and $\alpha_{j}$ is a root of it.
$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} ,$i$)$.
$f(x)=x^{3}-2$ take $\sqrt[3]{2}$ being a root but $i$ is not when we effect $\phi$ on it .

I really wanna see the explantion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not really satisfied with the given solution, since it does not point out, that normality of $L/K$ is important.

This is my proof:

First, note that we can assume $L$ to be finite over $K$, if not, we can always replace it by the normal hull of $K(\text{coefficients of the } f_i)$. Also, note that your solution also implicitly assumes $L/K$ to be finite without saying it and without giving an argument why this is allowed...

$\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ have the same minimal polynomial over $K$, hence there is an $K$-isomorphism $$K(\alpha_i) \to K(\alpha_j), \alpha_i \mapsto \alpha_j$$

Note that $L(\alpha_i)/K(\alpha_i)$ is algebraic. By a fundamental lemma about algebraic field extensions, we can extend this homomorphism to a $K$-homomorphism

$$\sigma: L(\alpha_i) \to \overline K$$

Here comes the crucial point: A priori we do not know that the image of this map is contained in $L(\alpha_j)$ (and it might be false if $L/K$ is not normal). But in the normal case, we have the following argument to show it:

We have $\sigma(K(\alpha_i)) = K(\alpha_j) \subset L(\alpha_j)$ and $\sigma(L) \subset L \subset L(\alpha_j)$, where the crucial inclusion $\sigma(L) \subset L$ holds **since $L/K$ is normal!**

Thus we have shown $\sigma(L(\alpha_i)) \subset L(\alpha_j)$, i.e. we have found a $K$-homomorphism $L(\alpha_i) \to L(\alpha_j)$. Any field homomorphism is injective, hence we obtain $[L(\alpha_i):K] \leq [L(\alpha_j):K]$. We can repeat the argument with $i,j$ swapped to obtain $[L(\alpha_j):K] \leq [L(\alpha_i):K]$, hence $[L(\alpha_i):K] = [L(\alpha_j):K]$ and in particular $[L(\alpha_i):L] = [L(\alpha_j):L]$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your answer is specifically perfect. Thank you.

Comment: However, actually I do not know why you can extend to $\phi$ I do not know that lemma :(

Comment: It is for example Theorem $2.8$ in Chapter V of Serge Lang's Algebra. Note that this Lemma/Theorem is essential for the proof that the algebraic closure is unique (up to isomorphism). So any book, that proofs this, also proofs this Lemma.

Comment: I saw the lemma you said. But that lemma does not tell $\sigma$ is an extension of $K(\alpha_i)\to K(\alpha_j)$. So, we don't know if $\sigma(K(\alpha_i))=K(\alpha_j)$ is true. It extends an embedding $K\to \overline{K}$ to an embedding $L(\alpha_i)\to \overline{K}$ not the isomorphism you said.

Answer (score 0):

The elements you are adding ($\alpha_i,\alpha_j$) are roots of $f_i$ and $f_j$. Now there exists as you say $\phi:L(\alpha_i)\to L(\alpha_j)$ which is the identity on $K$ and which sends $\alpha_i\mapsto \alpha_j$ (this is because $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ have the same polynomial over $K$, so your counterexample does not apply here). Now $f_i(\alpha_i)=0$ so applying $\phi$ $f_i$ is sent to a polynomial which is zero in $\phi(\alpha_i)=\alpha_j$, so it is a multiple of $f_j$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_j$. It is irreducible because a factorization after appliying $\phi$ yields a factorization in $L(\alpha_i)$ just by applying $\phi^{-1}$. So you have $f_i=f_j$.

If you still have questions, just ask!

Comment: In second solution, I do not mention that there is an isomorphism from $L(\alpha_{i})$ and $L(\alpha_{j})$. Why you have that? Because $\alpha_{i}$ and $alpha_{j}$ have the same irreducible $f(x)$ in $K[X]$, so we just have an isomorphism between $K(\alpha_{i})$ and $K(\alpha_{j}),$ how can you expand it?

Comment: And is it $\alpha_{j}$ is a root of $\phi(f_{i})$ because $\phi(f_{i})(\alpha_{i})=0$ then suppose that $f_{i}=a_{m}x^{m}+...+a_{0}$ (take $\alpha_{i}$ is a root), so $\phi(f_{i})(\alpha_{i})=\phi(a_{m})\phi(x^{m})+...+\phi(a_0)= a_{m}\alpha_{j}^m+...+a_0=0$ ($\phi \in Gal(H/L)$, $a_{i} \in L$)

Comment: Fix an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $K$ containing $L$. $K(\alpha_i)\to K(\alpha_j)$ extends to $K(\alpha_i)\to \Omega$ and because $L$ is normal $L$ is sent to itself, so $L(\alpha_i)=LK(\alpha_i)$ goes to $LK(\alpha_j)=L(\alpha_j)$.

Comment: However can you show me how can we have $\phi$ from $L(\alpha_{i})$ to $\Omega$

Comment: $\phi K:\to \Omega$ always extend to algebraic extensions of $K$. Start with $K(\alpha)$. To do this just consider $K[x]\to \Omega$ given by sending the variable $x$ to a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$; quotient by the kernel and here is your extension. Finite extensions are finitely generated, so just iterate this procedure (for infinite extensions you need Zorn's lemma).